# public: static constant string declaraion/initialization issue

Tags: c++, string, c++11, c++14, c++17

I wish to create static constant string variables protocol list but I am facing problems regarding the same.

- Build System : Visual Studios 2017
- Development/Target Architecture : x64
- Development/Target OS : Windows 10 Professional (64-bit)
- Application Development Platform : Win32 API (Windows SDK 10.0.17134.0)

Error :

> Error LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "public: static class
>   std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class
>   std::allocator<char> > const Protocol::serviceVersionRequestStr"
>   (?serviceVersionRequestStr@Protocol@@2V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@B)

Protocol.h

```
class Protocol
{
public:
    static const std::string        libraryVersionRequestStr;
    static const std::string        serviceVersionRequestStr;
    static const std::string        libraryVersionResponseStr;
    static const std::string        serviceVersionResponseStr;
    static const std::string        restartStr;
    static const std::string        identifyUserStr;
    static const std::string        registerUserStr;
    static const std::string        deleteUserStr;
    static const std::string        identifyUserSuccessStr;
    static const std::string        identifyUserWithdrawStr;
    static const std::string        identifyUserwithdrawSuccessStr;
    static const std::string        identifyUserwithdrawFailureStr;
    static const std::string        positiveAcknowledgementStr;
    static const std::string        negativeAcknowledgementStr;
//Some Public and Private methods
}
```

Protocol.cpp

```
std::string libraryVersionRequestStr        = std::string("GetLibraryVersion");
std::string serviceVersionRequestStr        = std::string("GetServiceVersion");
std::string libraryVersionResponseStr       = std::string("LibraryVersion:");
std::string serviceVersionResponseStr       = std::string("ServiceVersion:");
std::string restartStr                      = std::string("RestartService");
std::string identifyUserStr                 = std::string("IndentifyUser");
std::string registerUserStr                 = std::string("RegisterUser");
std::string deleteUserStr                   = std::string("DeleteUser");
std::string identifyUserSuccessStr          = std::string("IdentifyUserSuccess:");
std::string identifyUserWithdrawStr         = std::string("IdentifyUserWithdraw");
std::string identifyUserwithdrawSuccessStr  = std::string("IdentifyUserWithdrawSuccess:");
std::string identifyUserwithdrawFailureStr  = std::string("IdentifyUserWithdrawFailure:");
std::string positiveAcknowledgementStr      = std::string("Ack_");
std::string negativeAcknowledgementStr      = std::string("Nack_");
```

If I attempt to initialize static constant string during definition, I get an error

e.g. : `static const std::string        negativeAcknowledgementStr = std::string("Nack_");`

> Error (active)    E1591   a member of type "const std::string" cannot have
>   an in-class initializer

For this project, as I am adhering to C++17 standard, I solved the error by adding the `inline` keyword and initializing my variable using definition.

```
static inline const std::string     negativeAcknowledgementStr = std::string("Nack_");
```

Questions :

1. Is this something that was introduced in C++17 standard or something forced bu Visual C++ compiler? I had previously written code in gcc using C++14 where I had defined static constant string variable in class with public access modifier in a header file and initialized them in separate source file.
2. **What are other ways I can achieve the same (apart from inline keyword)**?

Comment: If you are going to separate the declarations from the initializations, you have to qualify the variables in the initializations to get rid of the linker errors, eg: `std::string Protocol::libraryVersionRequestStr = "GetLibraryVersion";` and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed the class name and the const keyword in your definitions

```
const std::string Protocol::libraryVersionRequestStr = std::string("GetLibraryVersion");
```

etc. etc.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my mistake, I wasted a lot of time wondering why it didn't work.